# Abnt2 keyboard does not work on macbook pro 13 Early 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, high-sierra

I'm trying to use an Abnt2 keyboard on my Macbook Pro 13, Early 2015, and I'm having some problems.

It's a Multilaser Metal War TC185: suporte.multilaser.com.br/downloads/detalhe/TC185 (I'm using this same keyboard on a linux computer without problems.)

I added the Brazilian keyboard Abnt2, as can be seen in the image below:
[image]

The keys were all identified, no problem at this point.

However, when I start typing, the letters are repeating themselves. For example: if I try to type "apple" at a normal speed it is coming out as "appppllle".

Given this problem, I tried to disable the Key repeat option and also increase the delay, but did not solve anything:
[image]

And the last problem are the shortcuts. The equivalent of `Command + Tab`, which should be `Alt + Tab` does not work, as well as other shortcuts with Control key or select files with shift for example.

What do I need to do to use an Abnt2 keyboard with my macbook?

[image]

Comment: What is the make and model of your external keyboard that you are trying to use?

Comment: @TomGewecke it's a Multilaser Metal War TC185: http://suporte.multilaser.com.br/downloads/detalhe/TC185/
PS: I'm using this keyboard on a linux computer and it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got a [new keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BB9OZH8) and it works.
So the problem was my [multilaser](http://suporte.multilaser.com.br/downloads/detalhe/TC185) keyboard that apparently has some issues with apple :/